# Should I store US States in my database or a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

How should I store States and Countries?

Option 1) I could create a database table called states, and have 'id', 'state', and 'state_abbr'.  I could then reference that by 'id' in the users table.

Option 2) I could create a PHP array and use that to populate the states drop down menu, and avoid querying the database altogether.  The key for the array would be the value inserted in the database for that user.

States don't change, and so the data should be static.  What's the best way to store this information and why?  Wouldn't a PHP array be faster?  Why does it seem like the database is the best way to store it then?

Thoughts?

Comment: I use a PHP array... whatever.

Comment: If states are also saved as part of other records in database then *yes* -- *with* the appropriate referential constraints. If not, then I see no particular advantage of one approach over the other. I would  not worry about "speed" here. There are other mechanisms to deal with that, if needed.

Comment: Storing it in an array would work faster, but using a database is more versatile and allows easy export and import of data, as well as its manipulation.

Comment: If texas decides to become independent what would your update policy look like?

Comment: I tend to stay away of databases if the data is purely static, because DBs are always gonna be *the* bottleneck like it or not, but as @pst points it depends on what you need this data for.

Comment: I would add that if the states are in the database, then they are available for other technology.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A wise database designer once told me, "Everything you know about state codes is wrong."

- These are two-letter codes, not abbreviations. ([The abbreviation for California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations#Current_use_of_traditional_abbreviations) is "Calif.", and the abbreviation for Ohio is "Ohio".)
- [There are more than 50 of them](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apb.htm).
- Not all of the two-letter codes refer to states. They also refer to "possessions" like "Federated States of Micronesia" and "Palau".
- They're not unique. One two-letter code, AE, refers to four different military "states" (Armed Forces Europe, Armed Forces Canada, Armed Forces Middle East, and Armed Forces Africa).
- Military "state" codes may change as troop strength changes. Send a few hundred thousand troops into Africa, and you're likely to see the code for Armed Forces Africa change from "AE" to "AF".
- There are a dozen or so territories that aren't yet in this list. Some of these are of strategic interest (Wake Island, Midway Islands, etc.), and their status could easily change.

Given that you're not likely to know all these things about such a common thing as USPS state codes, it just makes more sense to store them in a table. Tables are easier to maintain at run time than a PHP array is.

Comment: You could have simply said "it makes sense to store them in a table"  :)

Answer (score 7):

Because the database is the best way to store it.

What if next year your company decides to go international?
So now you need countries, and a dependent dropdown for states.

So you need to add europe, then africa.. Thats a TON of countries, along with a ton of states. You will need one big array.

Then your boss wants a report by country.

Much easier to manage if you have it all in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else is wondering the same thing.  I am currently in the process of designing an application, and to ensure data integrity, I wanted to create a country and state table. I also have cities, but I'm going let the users populate that I think as they enter addresses.

Now i say that, because at some point, I do hope my application will go international.

So, my current DB for countries has 249 records. (I removed some that don't have a population)

States, on the other hand was a bit harder cause not every country refers to them as states. (There are states, provinces, departments, parishes, Territories, districts, regions, and maybe some others.) But that table contains 3438 records for now.

Now i may vary well be wasting my time researching this information, as there may even be a database of this stuff online that i could simply reference with an API of some sort, but for now i got my info from something called the iso 3166   (-1 for countries  -2 for states. (I believe))

So the reality is, I will likely never see business from some of these countries, but they are there for now.

I've also created a table for formatting currency values properly. That's also a bit difficult as I've only fond the needed information for a handful.

But DB design does seem to get a little complicated when you have to account for the differences in information in various countries.

But to ultimately answer your question, if you are solely doing business in the US, hard coding or using a database would work, but States do change. Although it's been a while since we've added new states, it does happen, and may happen again soon. So a DB would be easier to manage I would think for any changes. Plus, if you decide to display additional information associated with the state, all you'd have to do is add some columns and all your references would display that information.

My view is to not have data hard coded in the code, but I'm not a professional. Even things that you thought would never change like gender, has proven that it too can change with all these Trans terms people are coming up with these days.